# Is there anyway to programmatically catch the lost focus (deactivation) of a PowerPoint slideshow window due to a hyperlink click?

Tags: vba, focus, interop, powerpoint, slideshow

I'm trying to find a PowerPoint event that would help me to catch the lost focus (deactivation) of the current slideshow.
In my slideshow a slide has a hyperlink. When the link is clicked, the default browser is opened to the respective page and, of course, my slideshow losses the focus. When the browser is closed, the slideshow automatically receives the focus.
Is there any way to catch either the slideshow window deactivate or activate event? I tried any possible events (WindowActivate, WindowDeactivate) without success, as they are referring to the presentation, not to the slideshow. Or maybe any way to detect that a link was clicked?

Adrian

P.S. I'm using this in an interop (C#) PowerPoint add-in, but I can handle VBA also.

Comment: http://youpresent.co.uk/powerpoint-application-events-in-vba/ - maybe `WindowActivate`/`WindowDeactivate` ?

Comment: Or this one: http://officeoneonline.com/vba/events_version.html. As I said, I tried any event from there which seems related, without results.

Comment: If you've tried all the events and none work, then the answer is no.

Comment: Fair enough! I gave up anyway...